# Dropdown mobile menu sliding in from top by pressing the Icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

I want my mobile dropdown menu to slide in from top when the user clicks the "header-downbar-menu" icon and slide out to the top when the user clicks it again. For now the button can only show the menu but I don't know how to properly write JS for this part...

```js
var DropdownMenuDown = false;

function OpenDropdownMenu() {
  if (DropdownMenuDown == false) {
    document.getElementById("header-dropdown-menu").style.top = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.header-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header-dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-downbar-menu" onclick="OpenDropdownMenu()">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div class="header-dropdown">
  <div id="header-dropdown-menu" class="header-dropdown-menu">

  </div>
</div>
```

I can't make the var "DropdownMenuDown" work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you using **toggle** for this.

Look here:

```js
function showMenu() {
  var topmenu = document.querySelector('.topmenu');
    topmenu.classList.toggle('show-me');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
}

.topmenu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  top: -60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 99;
}

.show-me {
  top: 0 !important;
}


button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div class="topmenu">
  </div>
  <button onclick="showMenu()">Menu pls!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i just have read your question. i think you are not aware of the selector of document. in your case, the code should be like this.

```
var DropdownMenuDown = false;

function OpenDropdownMenu() {
  if (DropdownMenuDown == false) {
    document.getElementByClassName("header-dropdown-menu").style.top = "0px";
  }
}
```

"header-dropdown-menu "is not id, but classname!